# DDD: Concrete Type per user ROLE on Bounded Context. Identity and Access

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design

Im stuck with designing the Identity and Access of my project against DDD.
I have Roles like Marketer, Coordinator, Planner in the system.
What I did was created concrete type for each role with their information save on table name `people`(name, email). and for the credentials I have `users` table (username, password) and table `roles`. Basically people and users table have the same id. (when I create user, I will also create person(people) and assign the id=user_account_id.

My problem is it seems like its not natural to check the role of the user to determine which concrete type I should instantiate. And I also have discriminator column in my `people` for each type. And I dont even know if creating concrete type per Role is a good idea.

I was thinking its better when I have concrete type so I can do something like

```
$inquiry = $marketer->makeInquiry($client, $subject);
```

instead of

```
$inquiry = new Inquiry($client, $subject, $marketer);
```

I also came out with idea of just using the `id` instead of the concrete type instance, but having problem when I need to display information about the person(`people`) like his name because I only have the id.

So, what is the best approach for this problem?

I am using Symfony2 and Doctrine (if it matters) but I think it is also applicable even with other technologies like ASP MVC and EF.

Comment: I'm not too sure if it's a good idea or not to put behavior on roles, but if I was to do it I would use an interface segragation approach where `Marketer` would implement something like `ICanMakeInquiry`. Therefore, if the implementer changes it's much less work to re-factor and it's a cleaner seperation of concerns.

Comment: Have a look at the Identity & Access part of the Implementing Domain-Driven Design book of Vaughn Vernon? There are some great explanations on how the I&A context plays nice with others, using anti-corruption layers.

Comment: yes Ive read about it but my brain hurts after reading it :) regarding your comment on @gert answer. isnt it youre taking away the logic from domain entity to service?

Comment: Which logic? Querying a user in a specific role is not really business logic, it's simply orchestration, which is the responsibility of the application service. The fact that the aggregate's method requires an author is what defines the logic, if we can call this logic. However, note that authorization is usually not really considered as part of the domain, but here you get it for free with domain concepts.

Comment: i dont know if i understand it correctly but based on a lot of articles ive read. authentication is application concern but authorization is business concern.

Comment: Well, it can be, but there's a lot to consider and sometimes you cannot be as rigorous with authorization rules as you are with domain invariants for instance. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dddcqrs/OIgCfeVb_Tw

Comment: thanks for the reference. do you think its ok to have reference only with the id of the user having the specific role? if so, how can i get information about the user like its name? its hard to model considering the orm capabilities. but ive read article to reference id on write. then query object and viewmodel for display. that way even its ok that the orm object only reference id. but im not sure if i get it correctly. and not sure how to do it

Comment: Well I'm not sure about what I will be saying, but in theory, an `Inquiry` is not getting created by a `marketerId`, it's being created by a `Marketer`. Therefore, it seems semantically correct to pass a `Marketer` instance to the `Inquiry` constructor, even if at the end the `Inquiry` will only hold onto the `Marketer`'s id. That way, you also get authorization for free (only a marketer can create an `Inquiry`). Now for reading data, you might have to use multiple repositories to construct your DTO's and that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a good idea to have subclasses for either `Role` or `People` (it's not entirely clear to me whether you refer to both).

For `Role` it isn't because the "type" of role (Planner, etc.) is just an attribute of `Role`, not a subtype. A role subtype would be something like a `PersonRole` or `CompanyRole`.

For `People` it doesn't seem a good idea because

1. Roles can change. Subtypes are meant to be (practically) immutable, like a `Bike` will always be a `Vehicle` of type "bike" and never turn into a `Car`.
2. It would block the possibility to assign two roles to a person *by architecture*. Architectural constraints are the hardest ones to change. Maybe presently it's not a question whether a person can have multiple roles, but in the future it may.

When it comes to differences of behavior based on a person's role you should consider other behavioral patterns than inheritance. Also look at [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: how will I model my domain? like Marketer, Coordinator? which are basically types of user in the system. Is it okay to do 
$inquiry = new Inquiry($client, $subject, $marketer); instead of $inquiry = $marketer->makeInquiry($client, $subject); ?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't subtype users. I would inject Marketer behavior into a user, e.g. Strategy pattern, based upon a user's role. Maybe it's none of both alternatives, maybe you should have an InquiryFactory.

Comment: Basically the behaviour does not change per role. Like if Marketer or Admin make Inquiry lets say. $inquiry = $marketer->makeInquiry($client, $subject); and same goes with Admin. the only thing here is that we know who created the Inquiry. If thats the case should I use just the id of the creator? But how can I get information about the creator, like its name.

Comment: If it's not about behavior you shouldn't use inheritance anyway. The id should be enough I guess.

Comment: ok I get your point. Another question. how will you separate Identity and Access from your domain. like here basically Marketer and Coordinator are user roles.  Can you give example implementation regarding this concern? How should I make the Inquiry? instantiating it directly? But shouldnt be theres someone who is making the Inquiry? and not being instantiated directly?

Comment: Please ask a new question if the topic changes.

Comment: I dont know, but I think its still relevant to my post regarding Identity and Access with regards to Roles

Comment: Your question is about inheritance yes or no. I answered that question. I have no idea how to implement "Identity and Access" (don't even know what you mean exactly) because I don't know the stack you work in (except EF). Implementation is a different question. Asking a new question will attract a new potential of answerers.

Comment: Making roles explicit and concrete has the advantage of making your code more expressive while having authorization checks for free: `author = someService.authorFrom(userId); someAggregate.someOperationThatMustBePerformedByAnAuthor(author);`.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes but specific to User role, which is part of Identiy and Access Management AFAIK. I think I have to change the title of my question